# Booting Problem in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, 17.10, lenovo

I installed ubuntu 17 using usb in my pc First. Now I  installed ubuntu 16.04  in my pc. The problem is when I tried to start the system, my loading screen starts with ubuntu 17 and then redirect to ubuntu 16.04. While staring and shutdowning it shows ubuntu 17. please  help me to solve this issue

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is it just an "aesthetic" thing, or do your system misbehave in some way? Do you get any errors? Is there something you can't use/does not work properly?

Comment: Yes  most of the application runs slow, browser misbehaved , and i changed kernel because my kernel not supported many system app.@MrShunz

Comment: As a suggestion, since there is a newer LTS release (18.04), you shoul try _upgrading_ your installation, since downgrading it's often hit-or-miss.